# Adding Method From Library

Tags: java, android, methods

I have a library which I've added to my project which contains the method getQueryResults the problem is - this method used to be in the project it's self and now has been moved into the library - how can I reference it's new location in the library to avoid the error:

```
The method getQueryResults(String) is undefined
```

SOURCE:

```
@Override
    protected InputStream doInBackground(String... params) {
        int result = 0;

        {
            Log.i("url...", Base_URL);

            try {
                stream = getQueryResults(Base_URL);
```

Comment: Firstly add the library and then use ClassName objName; objname.getQueryResults(Base_URL);

Answer (score 0):

As far as i can tell with your given information , You have to make an object of the class in which this method is available in the library or if its static you can call it with the class name and also don't forget to import the class.

Eg If class name is A which contains this method

```
  @Override
protected InputStream doInBackground(String... params) {
    int result = 0;

    {
        Log.i("url...", Base_URL);

        try {
            A a = new A();
            stream = a.getQueryResults(Base_URL);
```